# Cakephp Security.salt in wrong file by mistake

Tags: php, security, cakephp

I made a mistake when installing a previous Cakephp 2.3.4 in the `Security.salt` parameter.

I changed the `Security.salt` keys in the file `lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php` instead of making them in the file `app/Config/Core.php`.

Now my site is running on production and it has more than 25,000 user accounts with passwords.

I discover the error when upgrading to the last version 2.4.5.

What should I do now? should I make changes again in `lib/Cake/Utility/Core.php`?

If I make changes in `app/Config/Core.php` users would not be able to connect any more.

I'm really confused about this matter.
Does this represent a security issue?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it would not be good to you to change that in `core.php`, and I personally don't recommended that, assuming that already changed after installing CakePHP. However I am quite worried why did you tried to change that file as you had that "massive amount" of users (for that action). You should read a little more about Cake I think, and probably [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html#optional-configuration). Although it is mentioned as a *Optional Configuration*, it more like a ***"Must do" Configuration***, and do it just after install, or at most, before going to production.

If that was your case, and you want change this Security Salt with a lot of users already engaged on the website, you could do a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) approach, and hack your system to get the passwords and than covert them. But I would suggest a more elegant way.

Now, consider the [`Security::hash()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security%3a%3ahash) function, you can do something like this:

```
$myHash = Security::hash($text, 'sha1','my-salt');
```

Assuming that you are using the standard hash algorithm, SHA1, if you just passed true as third parameter, would give you the same hash if some one created that password on your system. But as presented above, you can test new salts...
So, you could base your self to do this:

- Continue to use the normal website;
- Create a new table for users (a copy on the same database);
- When an user login you your main site, check if your user exists on the new user table,
  if not, add it with an different Salt, by using that code above.
- Once all (or enough) of your users have done this, you can just change the `Security.salt` and swap the user tables.

It is not a very clever way, but one way to solve this without going too in depth on that. To help that work faster, you maybe could sent e-mails in mass, to all users, saying that you need them to change their passwords for improving the site security an so on...

In this particular case, if you want to just correct that salt key changed in the wrong file, you can 
**[check it here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php#L845)**, copy and paste it back where it should be. Although you can see that the branch listed (and the only 2.x) is 2.5, I've checked and it is the same value for the versions 2.3.0 and 2.3.5, thus, there is no reasonable explanation why 2.3.4 would have a different one. Using that should give you back exactly where you was before, with no problems.

Comment: Hello Patrick Thank you As said it was a mistake done since months ago but only now that I saw it :( Now the site is on production and it's working with the original Security.salt of Cakephp I would change it for security purpose BUT without affecting users to connect on the site The mistake is that we changed the key on the Debugger.php instead of core.php so it worked and we were happy (months ago) But now we see that there is a big security hole as it's using the same key as billions of other Cakephp installed on the web which would be a serious security loophole :( :( :(

Comment: How to create a script to convert from one hash to another ?

Comment: Yes, that's an common mistake, it happens, just remember that more often to avoid repeating this.About the script, I never really done that actually. But it is just somehow logical that you should be able to do that, swapping users passwords with other (new) hashes. I have played with hashes a little bit, maybe I could do that. I will try an approach for that, if I discover a way, I post another answer here.

Comment: I wrongly mentioned that you can create a script, sorry. Look more carefully thought in a different way, and I forgot that for changing the whole table hashes would not really possible, as you need to enter in a rainbow table approach. But anyway, I will edit the answer and give some useful ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to convert between the hashes. And that is the point. One uses the salt and hashing to prevent passwords from being read (and reversed!). (I know there *is a way* with advanced math and all that, but you're looking for practical solutions here).

What I suggest you can do in this case is to change the `Security.salt` in your `core.php` file.

*This will effectively lock everyone out*, but it will also boost your hashing because you have your own salt now.

Now, after you do this, you update the Login page to say:

> "We have tightened the security of our servers. As a result of this some accounts may have been locked out. If you have trouble logging in please use the *Password Reset* feature with the link bellow".

So now each user will reset their own password, therefore adding one using the new Salt and hash.

For you it looks like a huge load (25,000), but from the user point of view it's a minor inconvenience that has to be addressed only once.

And since not all the users will log in at the same time, this will not cause an overload on your server.

Another more *pro-active* approach would be to send out an newsletter explaining the situation entirely. But you are the judge of your who your audience is and if the are interested in the tech details.

In my opinion locking the accounts because of tighter Security is always better that allowing access with lose Security. (In other words... lock first! ask questions later!)